# How to change WooCommerce Mini Cart Title Atrribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently when you hover over the cart icon, it says "View your shopping cart". My client wishes this title to say "View your shopping basket".

I've looked everywhere for the template file with no luck and cannot seem to find any function.php code snippets that do the job.

The closest I got was finding 'storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php' file with the code below:

```
function storefront_cart_link() {
    ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
            <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
        </a>
    <?php
}
```

However nothing I do here has any impact on the website.

Solved:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated)
{
$translated = str_ireplace('Shipping', 'Delivery', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('View your shopping cart', 'View your shopping basket', $translated);

return $translated;
}
```

Comment: is this what you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481472/change-the-text-of-view-cart-button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated)
{
$translated = str_ireplace('Shipping', 'Delivery', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('View your shopping cart', 'View your shopping basket', $translated);

return $translated;
}
```

Works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a filter to the `get_text` hook, since this isn't a very ambiguous string:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'gb_modify_view_shopping_title');

function gb_modify_view_shopping_title( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){

    if($translated_text == 'View your shopping cart')
        return 'View your shopping basket';

    return $translated_text;

}
```

Comment: Hi George - I'm actually using this for another query. Is there anyway to 'reuse' it? I've attached it to my original post